# i got this error The getter 'idScreen' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: idScreen

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling, null, flutter-layout

`import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
import 'package:khan_pin/Screens/firstScreen.dart';
import 'package:khan_pin/Screens/homescreen.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
 }

 class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 var LoginScreen;
 return MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    title: 'KhanPin ',
    theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.blue),
    

    initialRoute: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser == null ? HomeScreen.idScreen : 
    FirstScreen.idScreen,
    routes: {
      FirstScreen.idScreen: (context) => FirstScreen(),
      LoginScreen.idScreen: (context) => LoginScreen(),
      HomeScreen.idScreen: (context) => HomeScreen(),
    }
    );
    }
   }~


 i got error as 
 The getter 'idScreen' was called on null.
 Receiver: null
 Tried calling: idScreen
```

Comment: can you include your `idScreen` for both page?

Comment: HomeScreen is null.

Comment: ```import 'package:khan_pin/Screens/firstScreen.dart';
 import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

 final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

 class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
 static const String idScreen = "home";
 HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
 }```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you've declared a variable in your build method:

```
var LoginScreen;
```

It's null and you are using LoginScreen.idScreen just after that. I believe you have a class with similar name. So just remove this variable and it will fix the issue.

Comment: thanks this fix my issue.

Comment: @Screation You are welcome. Happy Coding!!!

Comment: It's great you've found the solution, You can [check this to learn more about Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)